# When I put "pending" in an rspec controller test it still runs the CRUD helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Pending isn't working for me to stop CRUD ("get", "put", "post") etc helper methods from running in controller tests.

```
it "should update blah..." do
  pending "This is pending"
  put :update, { :id => @obj.id }
  expect(true).to eq(false)
end
```

This results in "put" being called, but the expect part doesn't get run. So pending appears to be working for the expectation, but not to stop the helper from running.

I'm using rspec 3.1

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semantics of `pending` changed in rspec3. Pending now means that a spec is expected to fail, so pending specs are now executed (and if the spec passes it is marked as a failure)

To stop a spec from running, use `skip`. There's more info in Myron Marston's post on the [changes in RSpec 3](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#changes_to__semantics_and_introduction_of_)